# Reading from file in python, with splitting

Tags: python, input

Trouble with python 3x with input and output from files

So, Im doing an assignment for my Computer science class and I'm having a slight problem. My professor wants us to add some lines of code that require the program to open up a .txt file and read the data from the .txt file through the program. In this case, my program is a monthly payment program.Usually, you'd ask the user to input how much he/she's borrowing, the interest rate, and the term in years. But, the data for all three of those are already pre-written in the .txt file, inwhich he wants us to read the data from. Now, I'm having trouble with my code.

This is my code:

```
import decimal

print("\t".join(s.rjust(15) for s in ("Payment", "Amount Paid", "Balance")))
print("-"*54)

filename = "LoanData.txt"
values = []

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        values.append([int(n) for n in line.strip().split(' ')])
for arr in values:
    try:
        balance,rate,term = arr[0],arr[1],arr[2]
    except IndexError:
        print ("Index error occured, a line doesn't have the crucial amount of entries.")

balance *= (1 + rate * term)
payment = balance / (12 * term)
total = 0
for month in range(12 * term):
    if balance < payment:
        payment = balance
    print(("{: >15.2f}\t"*3)[:-1].format(payment, total, balance))
    total += payment
    balance -= payment
```

and this is the error im getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Python/Desktop/loan.py", line 11, in <module>
values.append([int(n) for n in line.strip().split(' ')])
File "C:/Users/Python/Desktop/loan.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
values.append([int(n) for n in line.strip().split(' ')])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.5'
```

This is what the file looks like:

```
5000 5.5 10
25000 10.0 10
100000 8.5 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because you are trying to convert a decimal value (such as 5.5) into an int. Now, even if you change it to convert to a float, an additional fix is still needed as you can't use a float as an iterator for a for loop:

1.Change

```
balance,rate,term = arr[0],arr[1],arr[2]
```

To

```
balance,rate,term = int(arr[0]),arr[1],int(arr[2])
```

2.Change:

```
values.append([int(n) for n in line.strip().split(' ')])
```

To

```
values.append([float(n) for n in line.strip().split(' ')])
```

This will should get your code working. What it does is convert all inputs into floats, and then convert balance and term into integers so that they can be used in your for loop. I tried the code on my PC, and it should be working.

Comment: It works to an extent, this is what it prints though:

        Payment     Amount Paid         Balance
------------------------------------------------------
       71250.00            0.00     17100000.00
       71250.00        71250.00     17028750.00
       71250.00       142500.00     16957500.00
       It keeps doing this for 100 lines

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this output, or is this the correct output?

Comment: Well, it's not correct, but I think it might be the math. Basically I'm trying to calculate the loan payment per month and there's only 3 lines in the text while which is why I don't understand why it gives me 400.

Answer (score 0):

See the exception traceback. The error is on line 11, and it basically says '5.5' is not an int. Which is correct - It's a float (a decimal).
Line 11 is currently:

```
values.append([int(n) for n in line.strip().split(' ')])
```

Try:

```
values.append([float(n) for n in line.strip().split(' ')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to call `int()` on a decimal value, or `float` in python. That's why it's not working.
try `int('5.5')` in your interactive shell(IDLE), and you get the same error.

Try this:

```
values.append([int(float(n)) for n in line.strip().split()])
```

This will do the job if you don't mind losing the precision of your values, as `int` will round them to a whole number, and if you don't mind them all being floats then just use `float` instead of `int`